# Client Server Program C Windows - Library conflict

Tags: c, windows, sockets, libraries

I've created a classic client server program in C on my Windows machine in Eclipse. The code itself doesn't generate any errors. The only error I do get is concerning the libraries. I have included the following libraries:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```

But there is an error that appears when I try to build the project:

```
error "ws2tcpip.h is not compatible with winsock.h. Include winsock2.h instead".
```

The only issue is that I have not included winsock.h and included only winsock2.h just as they specified.

How do I solve this issue?

**UPDATE**

I've now defined the libraries in the following order:

```
#define _WINSOCKAPI_   /* Prevent inclusion of winsock.h in windows.h */

#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```

But now I get more errors:

```
undefined reference to `socket@12'  
undefined reference to `gethostbyname@4'    
undefined reference to `connect@12' 
undefined reference to `htons@4'    
undefined reference to `WSACleanup@0'   
undefined reference to `closesocket@4'  
undefined reference to `WSACleanup@0'   
undefined reference to `WSAStartup@8'
```

**UPDATE 2**

I think maybe this warning might have something to do with the errors I still keep getting:

```
ignoring #pragma comment  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
```

Answer (score 1):

`winsock2.h` has a line at the top:

```
#define _WINSOCKAPI_   /* Prevent inclusion of winsock.h in windows.h */
```

You need to include `winsock2.h` before `windows.h`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't quite understand: what do I need to include before windows.h? Is it winsock2.h? Because I did that and added your #define but now I'm getting even more errors.

Comment: If you include windows.h, windows.h will include winsock.h. You need to include winsock2.h before windows.h to prevent this. Please update your question with the additional errors

Comment: I did that. Please take a look at the updated question.

Comment: @JohnSmith do you link with ws2_32.lib?

Comment: @JohnSmith, your previous error was a compile error. These new errors are linker errors which indicate that you have not linked against `ws2_32.lib` as fritzone specified. Note that you don;t need that `#define` in your code. That is already inside `winsock2.h`.

Comment: @fritzone Yes I've added `#pragma comment(linker, "/defaultlib:ws2_32.lib" )` (before `winsock2.h`), but still get the same errors.

Comment: Did you do a clean/recompile? And try this: `#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")`

Comment: @fritzone Yes I did a clean then build. And I still get the same errors with your #pragma.

Comment: I've updated the question again. Please take a look.

Comment: You never mentioned what compiler you're using. I suspect not Microsoft's because Microsoft's would recognize that pragma. You need to figure out how to link against that library for whatever compiler you're using.